# How do I get the text that present under the matched string in tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

I have a string value in tcl as

```
set out " ABC CDE EFG 
          123     456"
```

I want to get the text that is present below text "EFG".
As right now it is "456", but it can be anything so I need a way though which I can grep for "EFG" and get the text below it.

Comment: Exactly like that? With the `set out` in there too, just like that? Or are the two lines _actually_ the same length (or close enough) that we can count characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case what you actually have is two lines with groups of 3 alphanumeric characters separated by spaces with a large amount of leading whitespace prefixing the second line (`"\x20ABC\x20CDE\x20EFG\n[string repeat \x20 10]123[string repeat \x20 5]456"` will reproduce what you posted). In your example `[string range end-2 end]` would give you what you need. I'd suggest reading the file line by line and each time you see the EFG, on the next line extract the part you need (maybe using string range) and emit it.

For example (untested):

```
set state 0
set f [open $inputfile r]
while {[gets $f line] != -1} {
    if {$state} {
        puts [string range $line end-2 end]
        set state 0
    } else {
        if {[string match "*EFG" $line]} { set state 1 }
    }
}
close $f
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer takes some inspiration from Johannes Kuhn's answer, but I use `regexp` to get the word indices from the "keys" line.

```
# this is as close as I can get to a here-doc in Tcl
set out [string trim {
ABC DEF GHI
123     456
}]

# map the words in the first line to the values in the 2nd line
lassign [split $out \n] keys values
foreach range [regexp -all -inline -indices {\S+} $keys] {
    set data([string range $keys {*}$range]) [string range $values {*}$range]
}
parray data
```

outputs

```
data(ABC) = 123
data(DEF) =    
data(GHI) = 456
```

Comment: This is the sort of answer I would give.

Answer (score 1):

I Suggest splitting the string into the keys and values with

```
lassign [split $out \n] keys values
```

and then look for the string position in the keys and get the same range in the values

```
set start [string first "EFG" $keys]
set value [string range $values $start [expr {${start}+[string length "EFG"]-1}]]
```

wraping it in a proc and we get

```
proc getValue {input lookFor} {
    lassign [split $input \n] keys values
    set start [string first $lookfor $keys]
    set value [string range $values $start \
        [expr {${start}+[string length $lookfor]-1}]]
}
```

invoke it like that:

```
getValue $out "EFG"
```

Edit: how is the 2nd line aligned? With a tabulator (`\t`), spaces?